# VB6 program hangs (slows) Windows 7 64-bits but not in 32-bits. Any solution?

Tags: windows-7, loops, vb6, 32bit-64bit

We have a program coded in VB6 running well on Windows7 32-bit with a Dual core, at any time. Now we are trying on Windows7 64-bit (dual core), and our surprise is that it's not working so fine: In long process, long loops, the system becomes saturated (hangs with 50% processor use) and it's impossible to change to another program (for example: ALT+TAB doesn't work or works very slowly), like 5-10 years ago, when our computers had only one processor or core. Any idea? Any limitation? Any bottleneck with 64-bit SO and VB6 runtime?

*Old-fashion and not elegant solution at this time*: I can fix this with **Doevents** (We've tried it, and it works) disabling and enabling all the controls, but it's full of enabled/disabled controls and it's hard to manage this and return the correct state

Thanks in advance.

**Update Info**: If we are running 2 applications based on 32 bits mode (it notes in taskmanager like *32), when one of them hangs the Windows7, the ALT+TAB works fine between 32 bits applications and GUI works fine. But if we change to an application using 64 bits, the GUI doesn't reponse.

Comment: Why do you say CTRL+TAB? Switching programs is done with ALT+TAB usually. Unless you are talking about a multi-document-interface here...?

Comment: It's nonsensical that `DoEvents` would make the application *more* responsive. The only way that makes sense is if you're running a bunch of code in the UI handlers. If that's the case, stop doing that. `DoEvents` is never the answer. Fixing the design of your app is a much better option.

Comment: ups! sorry ALT+TAB. thx Tomalak

Comment: Cody, I know DoEvents it's not the solution, but it's the only way that I found. I think, it's not a design problem, it works fine on 32-bits base SO but not in 64-bits.

Comment: Does your program hang on different computers with W7/64? What kind of activity your program makes while looping - some disk or network IO perhaps? The latest may easily collide with antivirus for example or bad disk/network drivers or whatever slight misconfiguration of system; pure processor activity should never make application switching slow.

Comment: Arvo, we've tried on 3 differents machines with same result, one of them without antivirus. First time we found this effect was filling a grid (farpoint COM Spread v7) using network and disk data, then we tried a pure memory loop function (collapse an hier struct in this grid) with same result. It seems a problem with this COM control. I will do more tests with this assumption. Thx. I thought maybe it was a "must-know" that I don't know.

Comment: If you go into Control Panel -> Performance Information and Tools, what is your Graphics score?  I first had a video card with terrible performance on Windows 7 (score 1.0), and it really affected VB6 applications when refreshing grids, etc.

Comment: Scott is 3.4. But I insist in 32-bits works fine.

Comment: I did new tests with these COM grid, and I got that it works fine (not hang) filling 10k x 10k cells in 64-bits SO. Now I'm lost again, could it be the memory allocation?

Comment: It may _appear_ that DoEvents makes it more responsive but as mentioned by @Cody Gray this will not be the case. Are you running something on a timer if so try increasing the timer time.

Comment: Matt, no Timers; Only filling a grid with data from a dll-engine, collapsing rows or exporting data to a file. I seems a bottle neck with the WOW64, but I test with other code (long loops) and it works fine.

Comment: @Cody: How would you redesign this VB6 app so that it *doesn't* do lots of work in UI handlers? And `DoEvents` *does* make an app more responsive, if a bit slower.

Comment: @Matt, you had reason, a timer hangs something. thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, thank you for your comments. At the end, after 3 days, we found the problem!

After a lot of buildings with differents paths in the code, we found a method that enables the tooltips on a Farpoint Spread v7 with the methods (textTip/textTipDelay):

```
fpspreadControl.TextTip = TextTipFloating 
fpspreadControl.TextTipDelay = 250
```

This control is contained on a Form that never unload, only we hide it. If we unload the form or we comment these two lines of code, the problem disappears.
Maybe Matt had the right path to the solution, some Timer in the control that launch the tooltip event hangs or hooks something in the system.

Thx again.

Comment: After install the last upgrade (7.0.56) of the Spread Control, it works fine always.